# segmentation fault in my erlang application

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, erlang-otp

I got a core dump file and using gdb on that revealed that it is a segmentation fault. I have no clue as to what might be the issue!

```
  Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
  #0  enqueue_task (ptp=<optimized out>, ptqp=0x0) at beam/erl_port_task.c:327
  327 beam/erl_port_task.c: No such file or directory.
```

Any pointers as to what might be the issue ? Thanks!

Comment: That is some internal error. You probably should install some soure package to see the code. At least, you should tell us, what erlang version are you using.

Comment: Hi @Lol4t0 Im using R15B03 on ubuntu.

Comment: I believe this a bug referenced [here](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.erlang.bugs/4606). Consider upgrading

Comment: Yes, this bug was fixed in R16B. R15B03 is old, and the current version of Erlang is 19.0. You should upgrade to a newer version.